# How to copy file from directory above?

Tags: nestjs

I have structure project like this.

```
- project folder
-- b.js
-- server (folder nestjs src)
```

I fix nest-cli.json

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "server"
}
```

I want to use file b in my main.ts file

```
import * as a from '../b.js';
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../b.js'
```

I add this file to nest-cli.json

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "server",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": [
      "b.js"
    ]
}
```

Now this file add to directory, which I set `"outDir": "./dist/server",`

But the error has not disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to test out `.` and `..`.

`.` gives you the current directory files. So `./b.js` could work.
`..` gives you directory above the current directory. So it thinks you are at `../b.js`, which doesn't exist.

If `/home/file/` was your project directory, and including `index.js` in `app.js` then using `../index.js` would mean `/home/index.js`.

However, if you use `./index.js`, you would get `/home/file/index.js`.

That's the difference between `.` and `..`.

Comment: How to change the path dynamically?

Comment: replace `import * as a from '../b.js';` with `import * as a from './b.js';`